# IntelliJ emacs keymap - how to configure Ctrl+L to recenter?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, intellij-idea

Ctrl+L in emacs runs `recenter-top-bottom` which centers the buffer with the current line appearing in the middle.

IntelliJ has an emacs keymap, but it doesn't have Ctrl+L. How do I configure it to have a similar functionality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Intellij has "Scroll to Center" bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>M</kbd>.

Add the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> binding in the keymap by going into "Settings | Keymap", choose "Emacs" or make a copy of the default keymap, find the current binding by entering "Scroll to Center" in the search box, double click on the line where the binding is defined, select "Add Keyboard Shortcut", type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> key sequence in the "First Stroke" text field and click OK.